# Count values from array of keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a JSON array looking like :

```
{
  "date": "01/01/2016",
  "duration": "duration : 1h30",
  "hour": "18:30",
  "subject": "subject",
  "price": "free",
  "link": "link",
  "link/_text": "something",
  "description": "something",
  "location": "somewhere"
},
{
  "date": "02/01/2016",
  "duration": "duration : 1h",
  "hour": "11:00",
  "subject": "subject",
  "price": "free",
  "link": "something",
  "link/_text": "something",
  "description": "something",
  "location": "somewhere"
},
{
  "date": ["26/01/2016","27/01/2016"],
  "duration": "duration : 2 days",
  "hour": "18:30",
  "subject": "subject",
  "price": "free",
  "link": "link",
  "link/_text": "something",
  "description": "something",
  "location": "somewhere"
}....
```

I would like to detect when I have two days events.

Using angularjs & ionicframework I was able to use a {{countDates(event.date)}} function as this :

```
$scope.countDates = function(eventObj) {
    return Object.keys(eventObj).length;
};
```

It usually returns the amount of unique dates keys, so when I fetch 10 items it returns 10...but on "to...from" dates it returns 2, so I was able to build a template with :

```
<div collection-repeat="event in events | limitTo:rssnb" class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap" ng-click="browse(event.link)">
    <div ng-if="countDates(event.date) == 2">
          <b>from</b> {{event.date[0]}} <b>to</b> {{event.date[1]}} </br>
          at {{event.hour}}<br />
     </div>
     <div ng-if="countDates(event.date) != 2">
          on the {{event.date}} at {{event.hour}}<br />
     </div> 
</div>
```

I think it is :

- dirty...
- will work only if I fetch more than two items. If I fetch 2 items it will display "from... to..." in the template even if the event is only 1 day long.

Can you suggest a better way to detect if a key value is unique or double ?

Thanks a lot,

yts

Comment: You can probably use angular.isArray to check if it is an array..and then check length

Comment: have you tried this, instead of keeping the single dates as strings, keep them in the same format as the ones with two dates. After that, change the statement `countDates(event.date) != 2` to this `countDates(event.date) < 2` and see if it works...

Answer (score 0):

I think its best to keep the dates in JSON as arrays like similar to the the ones with two dates:

```
{
  "date" : [...],
  ...
}
```

And you might want to change the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events | limitTo:rssnb" class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap" ng-click="browse(event.link)">
<div ng-if="countDates(event.date) > 1">
      <b>from</b> {{event.date[0]}} <b>to</b> {{event.date[1]}} </br>
      at {{event.hour}}<br />
 </div>
 <div ng-if="countDates(event.date) == 1">
      on the {{event.date[0]}} at {{event.hour}}<br />
 </div>
```

But if you want a unique date(if thats what you asked in the question), then you might want to use a `unique` filter from the angular.filter module which will give out unique values....

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angular you can use this:

```
<div collection-repeat="event in events | limitTo:rssnb" class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap" ng-click="browse(event.link)">
    <div ng-if="angular.isArray(event.date) && countDates(event.date) == 2">
          <b>from</b> {{event.date[0]}} <b>to</b> {{event.date[1]}} </br>
          at {{event.hour}}<br />
     </div>
     <div ng-if="!angular.isArray(event.date) || (angular.isArray(event.date) && countDates(event.date) != 2)">
          on the {{event.date}} at {{event.hour}}<br />
     </div> 
</div>
```

But also you should move all the logic inside ng-if to controller to keep the view clean.